# How to set Label.TextAlign=Justifiy

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to Justify text Like Below Link Image in label there have word justifications not a character currently my code is doing this. And i am using another fonts as well and it is a multi-language application so the text justification is work some times in English language only but i need another fonts too.

[image]

MyCode is below, Please check this.

```
public void Justify(System.Windows.Forms.Label label)
{
    string text = label.Text;
    string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(l => l.Trim()).ToArray();

    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        result.Add(StretchToWidth(line, label));
    }

    label.Text = string.Join("\r\n", result);
}
```

It is call next function

```
private string StretchToWidth(string text, Label label)
{
    if (text.Length < 2)
        return text;

    // A hair space is the smallest possible non-visible character we can insert
    const char hairspace = '\u200A';

    // If we measure just the width of the space we might get too much because of added paddings so we have to do it a bit differently
    double basewidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, label.Font).Width;
    double doublewidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text + text, label.Font).Width;
    double doublewidthplusspace = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text + hairspace + text, label.Font).Width;
    double spacewidth = doublewidthplusspace - doublewidth;

    //The space we have to fill up with spaces is whatever is left
    double leftoverspace = label.Width - basewidth;

    //Calculate the amount of spaces we need to insert
    int approximateInserts = Math.Max(0, (int)Math.Floor(leftoverspace / spacewidth));

    //Insert spaces
    return InsertFillerChar(hairspace, text, approximateInserts);
}
```

and last is this.

```
private static string InsertFillerChar(char filler, string text, int inserts)
{
    string result = "";
    int inserted = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        //Add one character of the original text
        result += text[i];

        //Only add spaces between characters, not at the end
        if (i >= text.Length - 1) continue;

        //Determine how many characters should have been inserted so far
        int shouldbeinserted = (int)(inserts * (i + 1) / (text.Length - 1.0));
        int insertnow = shouldbeinserted - inserted;
        for (int j = 0; j < insertnow; j++)
            result += filler;

        inserted += insertnow;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @mjwills please check this and let me know how can i do this.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37155195/how-to-justify-text-in-a-label

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes yes i followed that and use their code you can see in my question

Comment: Labels currently don't support justified text, I'd make a custom control adding space between characters. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068752/how-to-change-spaces-between-lines-in-winforms-label

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `Label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter`. There are several other options. You can see them here and try them out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.contentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes i tried this code but spacing is not adding.

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah i tried this and other align properties too but not returning result as i want.

Comment: You don't do that to a label, you create a custom component based on a label and paint the text the way you want. If you try to apply that to a label you won't get any result.

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes you have any example, because i can't understand how could i do this?

Comment: @Polo have you tried stepping through the code? For instance what is the value of `label.Text.Length` _before_ and _after_ you call `Justify()`?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis before the value is around 290 and and justifying 310.

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2016/Writing-your-Custom-Control-step-by-step

Comment: Here is something more advanced: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6913/Creating-a-professional-looking-GDI-drawn-custom-c

Comment: @ThadeuFernandes Sorry Your Example not Valid for me

Comment: @Polo Seems like the code you are using is not compatible with automatic word wrapping. Any text wider than the label width will not be justified.